# Limit Number of Inputs onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to allow only one entry of a text in the textarea once the button is clicked. If the button is clicked 2 or more times only one entry should be entered in the textarea.

### JAVASCRIPT:

```
function inyectarTexto(elemento,valor){
 var elemento_dom=document.getElementsByName(elemento)[0];
 if(document.selection){
  elemento_dom.focus();
  sel=document.selection.createRange();
  sel.text=valor;
  return;
 }if(elemento_dom.selectionStart||elemento_dom.selectionStart=="0"){
  var t_start=elemento_dom.selectionStart;
  var t_end=elemento_dom.selectionEnd;
  var val_start=elemento_dom.value.substring(0,t_start);
  var val_end=elemento_dom.value.substring(t_end,elemento_dom.value.length);
  elemento_dom.value=val_start+valor+val_end;
 }else{
  elemento_dom.value+=valor;
 }
}
```

### HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="inyectarTexto('nametField','hello world');" >Say hello world to text</a>
```

Here the issue is that if I click the link `Say hello world to text` two times the text `hello world` entered two times, however I only want one set of `hello world` should be entered if the link is clicked how many times.

Please help!

Comment: How about disabling the link after it's clicked?

Comment: @mikehomme: No I don't want to disable the link, thanks

Comment: Or emptying the text field each time the link is clicked... this way the text won't be appended back-to-back after each click.

Comment: How can I empty the text field?

Comment: `elemento_dom.value = ''`

Also, why are you using `elemento_dom.value+=valor`? Why not `elemento_dom.value = valor`?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/egbbagkm/

Comment: Why populate the global scope with an unnecessary counter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var clicked = false;

inyectarTexto = function (elemento,valor){
 var elemento_dom=document.getElementsByName(elemento)[0];
    if(!clicked){
        elemento_dom.value += valor;
        clicked = true;
    }
 }
```